# Maven exclusions best practices

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3, dependency-management

I'm using Maven2. When I look at the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` I see lots of:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

All of those are inlcuded in my pom as a dependencies as well. My question is, which is the policy to follow, leave it, excluded only version conflicts,  or exclude every single transitive dependency.

I couldn't see anything related to this in the manual.

Thanks!

Comment: The questions is why did you add the other dependencies to your POM if they are already coming as transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicity of dependecies is no issue withm maven - so you can leave this as it is.
(Every other artefacts depends on apache.logging - you don't need to worry abou that, maven takes care for you)

You just need to solve version confilcts or you can ommit dependecies that will be provided in run environment.

Best practice is (as stated krosenvold):

> include any dependency containing a
>   java class file that is directly
>   referenced by your code. So any class
>   that is referenced from your source
>   should be defined.

And dont worry about duplicity in dependecy tree

Answer (score 1):

You *should* (at minimum) include any dependency containing a java class file that is directly referenced by your code. So any class that is referenced from your source should be defined.

This creates a certain encapsulation of dependency-definitions; your project is responsible for defining its own dependencies, and they again define *their* dependencies. This is the stuff mvn dependency:analyze tells you about.

The maximum is slightly less well-defined and is typically driven by need. Several libraries can depend on different versions of a third library. In that case you can either supress one of them or just include the correct one in your pom. The version in your own pom will take precedence.

And sometimes you just have to include something to get the appropriate version (database drivers come to mind).

But the minimal dependency list is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you gave there you only need give the dependency which means to give only a dependency for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile but not for the others. This will make your pom's slim...